# Why does my wap website jumps to the wrong page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wap

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to make a WAP website.

In the default page, default.aspx, I have this Control:

```
<mobile:Command ID="com" BreakAfter="True" Runat="server" Click="com_Click">Login</mobile:Command>
```

default.aspx.cs

```
  protected void com_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             
           Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
```

When I click the button, the address bar shows 'http://loaclhost:1564/#__pbc1'.
It does not work, but in Opera it is normal. I don't know why.
I still need to do something?

Answer (score 0):

That's an anchor tag... It could be caused by the javascript library you're using. Often times, because an `a` tag requires an `href` item, `#` is used because it doesn't reload the page.

Try this first: `Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");` first to see if it helps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry  it still not work address bar shows http://loaclhost:1564/Default.aspx#_pbc1